# Does LiveData have to exist in the Repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm a beginner studying `MVVM` design patterns.

Looking at the code of `Google CodeLab` and other sample codes, a question arose.

As the title suggests, does `LiveData` necessarily exist in the `Repository`?

I've been using and observing `LiveData` in a `ViewModel` so far.
(There's no special reason, I just used it because I didn't know anything)

By the way, I looked at the code of `Google CodeLab` to study `Room`, and I saw that it uses `LiveData` (or `Flow`) in the `Repository` and reference this in `LiveData of the ViewModel`.

Sample code from other web sites was similar.

But I don't know why `LiveData` is in the `Repository` and uses the way it's referenced.

Since `LiveData` is used in the `Repository` in the code of official docs such as `CodeLab`, I am using it accordingly, but I do not know why.

In the `MVVM` pattern, does `LiveData` necessarily exist in the `Repository`? I'd appreciate it if you could explain why.

Comment: if we are allowed to use livedata in repository then why in google document it says `DON'T DO THIS! LiveData objects should not live in the repository.`     ?
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#livedata-in-architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveData is simply an observable data holder. It is lifecycle aware so it is a  good practice to use it for providing data to View from ViewModel. **LiveData** can now be replaced with **Flow** which have few benefits over **LiveData**.

From **Repository** to **ViewModel**, it is completely up to you whether you want a **LiveData/Flow** returned or simply return the model that you expect from DAO but still you will require a **LiveData/Flow** if you want to provide that model to **View** after receiving that model from **Repository** to **ViewModel**.

Comment: Thank you. I have one question.

You wrote `LiveData can now be replaced with Flow which have few benefits over LiveData`, but I don't understand why `Flow` is used when there is no benefits over `LiveData`..

Comment: I said Flow has few benefits over LiveData. You can search for differences between them and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

The MVVM pattern is more about designing software, and organising the architecture into separate layers. The View is the user-facing frontend, the Model is the backend where the data is handled.

The View Model sits between them, converting data from the Model into some form of UI state the View can display, and turning UI events like button presses into calls to the app's backend functions, in the Model.

`LiveData` and `Flow` (which are similar - one is Android and one is Kotlin) are ways of exposing data, which is ultimately what the Model does - producing data. Instead of just providing a single value on request, they're able to provide a *stream* of data.

And the View Model (which is the intermediary between the Model and View - they don't talk to each other) can take that `LiveData` or `Flow`, and either expose it directly to the View, or do some processing on it to produce data suitable for the View to display. That way you have a pipeline from the data producer (the Model) to the UI (the View). That's basically how MVVM works in general, this is just using the streaming/producer/reactive model to wire things up and make things like async operations simpler

This is worth a read, it explicitly mentions repositories as the data producer in this model:
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow